# calculation of median of every four row

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have a dataframe which looks like below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xboZ1.png)

I want to calculate median of LFC column but as you can see in dataframe these LFC values belong to  a gene. And for each gene there are four LFC values. I want to calculate the median of LFC values which are exclusive to the gene with using Gene name because some genes dont have 4 LFC values (they have 3).

I tried to calculate using R but I couldn’t do it.

Comment: Try `with(your_data, aggregate(x = LFC, by = Gene, FUN = median))` or `your_data$lfcMedianPerGene <- with(your_data, ave(x = LFC, Gene, FUN = median))` if you like to bind as new column to the whole data. It is easier to help if you provide data using `dput(your_data)`.

Comment: If your data frame is called `my_data`, then you can do `aggregate(LFC ~ Gene, data = my_data, FUN = median)`. If you can't get this to work, please include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can try to help you. You could also [edit] your question to make it clearer what format the expected output would be.

Comment: @AllanCameron it worked as a charm! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please get used to SO standards and do not provide images. Use dput() to provide example data that people can copy and paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library `dplyr` has been invented to perform group operations. In your data, you want to group by `LFC`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(LFC) %>%
  summarise(Median = median(LFC))
```